# How to use div+css make three columns in html

Tags: html, css

How to use div+css make three columns in html.

left and right columns width:auto, and middle one need width:990px(should be in the center) and they are height:100%.

HTML

```
<div style=" float:left; width:auto; height: 100%;background-color:#006;">Area1</div>
<div style=" float:left; width:990px; height: 100%;">Area2</div>
<div style=" float:left; width:auto; height: 100%;background-color:#006633;">Area3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For this type of functionality you can use display:table property for this. Like this:

```
html,body{height:100%;}
div{
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/K5H4e/

But it's not work till IE7 & below.

Comment: `display:table;` is nice, but unfortunately it has the drawback to expand their cells just like real tables do. This is mostly unwanted in layouts;)

Comment: It's not unwanted at all. display:table is created for these type of functionality & requirement.

Comment: well, you want your design to crash, only because there is an element in your column wich is broader then your defined width and expands the column's width accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

this will be easier using a [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) with three column .

Comment: It will be easier, but so would making the whole thing an image. A `table` should only be used for tabular data.

Comment: sometimes it IS better to use a table

Answer (score 0):

general you shoud use something like this: [Example on js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWy23/).

```
<div style="float:left;  background-color:#006;"   >Area1</div>
<div style="float:right; background-color:#006633;">Area3</div>
<div style="border:1px solid red;overflow:auto;"   >Area2</div>
​
```

Note: You won't get the height of the rows align that easily, since they are independent elements.

EDIT:
in order to have the `height:100%`work on your divs, you need the following:

```
html, body { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%; /* important! */
}

div {
min-height: 100%;
}
```

EDIT2: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWy23/1/)

Comment: Thank you for example first, let me try it ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="Division"><p>First Division</p></div>
 <div class="Division"><p>Second Division</p></div>
<div class="Division"><p>Third Division</p></div>​


.Division{
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAsXM/)

```
<div style="width:auto; height: 100%;background-color:#006; 
display: inline">Area</div>
<div style="width:990px; height: 100%; display: inline">Area2</div>
<div style="width:auto; height: 100%;background-color:#006633; 
display:inline">Area3</div>
```